# Проверка новых данных лучше в Контроллере или через JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

Приблизительно такой грамосткий и ужасный код получается :

```
  [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult AllCustomers(Customer customer, OldIdForCheck oldITNforcheck)
            {
                customer.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                customer.CustomerITN = customer.CustomerITN.Replace("  ", string.Empty);
                //_________________________________
                if (customer.CustomerITN != oldITNforcheck.OldITN)
                {
                    if (db.Custumers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerITN == customer.CustomerITN) != null || db.Founders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FounderITN == customer.CustomerITN) != null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.error = "Подобный ИНН уже существует. Каждый ИНН должен быть индевидуален";
                        return RedirectToAction("AllCustomers");
                    }
                }

                //..................................
                 if (!Regex.IsMatch(customer.CustomerITN, "^[0-9а-яА-Я?-]*$"))
                {
                    ViewBag.error = "ИНН может содержать только цифры";
                    return RedirectToAction("AllCustomers");
                }
                //..................................
                 if(customer.EntityType == "юридическое лицо")
                {
                    if (customer.CustomerITN.Length != 10)
                    {
                        ViewBag.error = "ИНН юридического лица состоит из 10 цифр";
                        return RedirectToAction("AllCustomers");
                    }
                }
                //..................................
                 if(customer.EntityType == "индивидуальный предприниматель")
                {
                    if (customer.CustomerITN.Length != 12)
                    {
                        ViewBag.error = "ИНН индивидуального предпринимателя состоит из 12 цифр";
                        return RedirectToAction("AllCustomers");
                    }
                }
                //_________________________________

                {
                    db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("AllCustomers");
```

Хотел спросить у знатоков, подобную проверку прямо на странице лучше проводит через JS или в контроллере все же лучше.

Comment: все важные проверки должны быть на сервере. На клиенте они могут дублироваться для повышения отзывчивости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При MVC архитектуре - на стороне сервера лучше валидировать форму, в модели. Там, где к бд обращение - в контроллере, а лучше в каком-нибудь валидаторе, чтобы метод не захламлять ифами.

Comment: То есть нужно сделать отдельную модель именно с теми пунктами изменяемой модели которые приходят от клиента ? Мне друг то же самое советовал но когда делаю модель с элементами основной модели то EF не узнает. То есть например время создания чтоб не менялось при обновлении лучше другую модель сделать, но как поступить ведь она не признает ее как модель из БД

Comment: Вообще да, нужно иметь одну модель для UI и одну модель для бд. Первая работает только с интерфейсом (валидация там же), а вторая только с базой данных. Непосредственно перед сохранением в бд конвертируете одну модель в другую, например, с помощью AutoMapper

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь